# Table generated by jquery aren't displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my spring application, each one of my views have this structure (html code after renderization of the jsp code):

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul id="mainTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home-Fornecedor" data-toggle="tab">Listagem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cadastra-Fornecedor" data-toggle="tab">cadastra</a></li>
    <li><a href="#altera-Fornecedor" data-toggle="tab">altera</a></li>
    <li><a href="#remove-Fornecedor" data-toggle="tab">remove</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home-Fornecedor">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Listagem</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default items">5</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default items">10</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default items">15</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default items">20</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Ordem <span class="caret"></span>

                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                <li><a class="ordem" href="0">id</a></li>
                                <li><a class="ordem" href="1">cnpj</a></li>
                                <li><a class="ordem" href="2">razaoSocial</a></li>
                                <li><a class="ordem" href="3">endereco</a></li>
                                <li><a class="ordem" href="4">contato</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table" id="main-Fornecedor">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col" data-property="#"></th>
                        <th class="col" data-property="id">id</th>
                        <th class="col" data-property="cnpj">cnpj</th>
                        <th class="col" data-property="razaoSocial">razaoSocial</th>
                        <th class="col" data-property="endereco">endereco</th>
                        <th class="col" data-property="contato">contato</th>
                        <th class="col" data-property=""></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="content"></tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="comando" data-nome="altera" data-action="/loja/Fornecedor/altera"></td>
                        <td class="comando" data-nome="remove" data-action="/loja/Fornecedor/remove"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <div align="center">
                <ul class="pagination pagina"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cadastra-Fornecedor">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="altera-Fornecedor">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="remove-Fornecedor">...</div>
</div>
```

inside the tab `Home`, I generate a table using a json file to fill it. THIS TABLE IS BEING GENERATED CORRECTLY  When I click in the button with text `cadastra` or `altera`, in the tab of same name, in some views I need insert a new structure similar to that. This last table are being generated with trunked rows.

The renderized code for the table is this:

```
<table class="table" id="Endereco">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col" data-property="#">#</th>
            <th class="col" data-property="id">id</th>
            <th class="col" data-property="logradouro">logradouro</th>
            <th class="col" data-property="numero">numero</th>
            <th class="col" data-property="complemento">complemento</th>
            <th class="col" data-property="bairro">bairro</th>
            <th class="col" data-property="cidade">cidade</th>
            <th class="col" data-property="estado">estado</th>
            <th class="col" data-property="cep">cep</th>
            <th class="col" data-property=""></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="content"></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td class="comando" data-nome="altera" data-action="Endereco/altera"></td>
            <td class="comando" data-nome="remove" data-action="Endereco/remove"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

the jquery code to insert the row in the table is this:

```
function load_content(lista, target, pagina, items, ordem, entity) {
    var atributos = [];
    $(".col").each(function () {
        var property = $(this).data('property');
        atributos.push(property);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: lista,
        data: {
            pagina: pagina,
            items: items,
            ordem: ordem
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        target.find("tbody.content").empty();
        $.each(json.item, function (index, item) {
            var row = $('<tr>');
            console.log(':linha');
            for (var i = 0; i < atributos.length; i++) {
                if (atributos[i] == '#') {
                    console.log('::checkbox');
                    row.append('<td><input type="checkbox" name="' + entity + '" value="' + item.id + '"></td>');
                } else if (atributos[i] == '') {
                    console.log('::comandos');
                    var col = $('<td>');
                    var group = $('<div class="btn-group">');
                    $(".comando").each(function () {
                        var nome = $(this).data("nome");
                        var action = $(this).data("action");
                        group.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary action" data-target="' + nome + '-' + entity + '" data-action="' + action + '/' + item.id + '">' + nome + '</button>');
                    });
                    col.append(group);
                    row.append(col);
                } else {
                    var token = item[atributos[i]];
                    console.log('::token = ' + token);
                    row.append('<td>' + token + '</td>');
                }
            }
            target.find("tbody.content").append(row);
            target.find("tfoot").each(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

the code above is used to create both the tables: either the one in the main page or the one in the `cadastra` or `altera` tabs, when one it's needed.

When I open this page in the browser and click in the button `cadastra`, I get this:

[image]

Looking in the developer tool from the browser, I notice inside the tag `<tbody class="content"></tbody>` the script generate one big line (`<tr>`) with the content of three (the block `<td>...</td>` in the image should be the start and end of one line), like that:

[image]

But in my json file I only have one item, which is displayed in the table with  this junk text I can't figure out where come from.

Anyone can tell me what's wrong here?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/h8Jnv/

Comment: The fiddle wasn't operational, fixed the errors: http://jsfiddle.net/h8Jnv/5/

Comment: Could you please update the fixed fiddle by providing more than one record within the JSON?

Comment: @wiesion http://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/M5G4D/

Comment: @wiesion in the jsfiddle and in the main page from my application it works, but when I try in a internal page don't work.

Comment: My first guess would be that the JSON is not what you're expecting it to be. Use the Network inspector and analyze the response from the JSON call.

Comment: @wiesion but I already check the json file through the newtwork inspector and I am sure the content it's what I expected to be.

Comment: @wiesion because this the main page is opened correctly, but the the internal pages (opened inside this main page) are opened with the malformed table

Comment: Oh then i guess you're having more td.col elements in the other tabs. You should be more specific at $(".col").each ... like $("#Listagem .col").each ...

Comment: @wiesion that's was the problem! (if you add an answer now, I will accept it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more precise when collecting the attributes to loop over, e.g.:

```
$("#TargetedTable .col").each(function () {
    var property = $(this).data('property');
    atributos.push(property);
});
```

Otherwise the loop from `for (var i = 0; i < atributos.length; i++)` will try to insert non-existing values from the JSON feed.